# data reference (dref) atom support in iOS

Tags: ios, mp4, quicktime

quiktime file format has suport for dref atom. Where actual video data can reside in separate file on webserver.

to test the feature I created a file with dref atom. http://vihosting.net/sample_iTunes_reference.mov

This file plays nicely on quicktime player, but iPhone/iPad gives error, i am not sure if this is issue with generated file or device support.

1. If iOS (iphone,ipad) suports dref atom.
2. If not is there any official document from apple which stats this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

AVFoundation (media framework used in iPhone/iPad) supports limited number of video codecs. The sample file you provided is encoded with a rare codec 3ivx D4 4.5.1 (some applications even cannot recognise it), which is not supported in iOS.

Encode video using either h264 or mpeg4 codecs and use .mov or m4v container for iOS.